# Combo Boxes With Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I've read that combo boxes cannot have multiple columns.  Which leaves me a bit stuck since what I want to do is display one field from a table, but return the corresponding value from a second field in the same table i.e.

I'd like to show CustomerNames in the combo box, but when the user selects a name, the CustomerID field is returned instead.  Whats the best work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple columns to implement it.

```
class Member
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
    public int ID{get;set;}

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}, {1}", Name, Address);
        }
    }
}

var members = new []
{
   new Member(){ID = 1, Name = "John", Address = "Addr 1"},
   new Member(){ID = 2, Name = "Mary", Address = "Addr 2"}
};

m_ComboBox.DataSource = members;
m_ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Description"
m_ComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
```

now you can access seleceted ID

```
var selectedID = m_ComboBox.CelectedValue();
```

Comment: Can this be pushed a bit further, i.e. display, Customer Address Lines 1,2,3 (three fields), but returning an AddressID (4th field)?

Comment: You should create an aggregation field that will provide description of the Member instance (Name + Address + e.t.c.)

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use ComboBoxes `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties

set the `ComboBox.DisplayMember` to the property you want to display. Use `ValueMember` for property you want to return. Then you can use the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` to get the current/selected `ValueMember`

Answer (score 1):

The value of the ComboBoxItem does not have to be the same as the Text, consider using the ID as the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the ComboBox to `"CustomerName"` and `"CustomerID"` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ValueMember` property.  You should set this to CustomerID.  After you bind to your combobox, the actual field displayed to the user will be the CustomerName, but when you want to get the value of 'CustomerName', it will return the CustomerID.

When you want to get the value of the combobox, simply reference the `SelectedValue`.

If you are adamant about displaying both of these in the combobox, there are some hackish ways of doing this but I would recommend reviewing your requirements again and seeing if it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can define KeyValuePair objects with your intended Ids and text fields. Feed them to the combo, since its Items property is a collection of objects. Then, for retrieval use a cast like

```
var x = (KeyValuePair)combo.Items[0];
```

and then acces then Key and Value properties of x.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tag property of ComboBoxItem to store the value.